# MySQL Query error - hidden mistake?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am trying to make a registeration form, but the sql query just won't work.. tried adding the consenants and removing them, adding the (') sign to the inserted data and removing them.. nothing works! i am not sure where my mistake is... can someone please help?

PHP Code:

```
      $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','wisdom') or die("CONNECTION ERROR");

  $query = "INSERT INTO net_users VALUES (NULL,'$fname','$mname','$lname','$dob','$uname','$pasw','$phone1','$phone2','$email',NULL,NULL,NULL,'$date');";

      if($mysqli->query($query)) echo "REGISTERED";
      else echo "<br><br>FAILED: ".$mysqli->error;
```

ERROR:

```
FAILED: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '123456789,987654321,b@b.b,NULL,NULL,NULL,14/12/04)' at line 1
```

data ($_POST):

```
Array ( 
[fname] => A   //$fname
[mname] => A   //$mname
[lname] => A   //$lname
[dob] => 2014-07-17   //$dob
[username] => bakriawad  //$uname
[password] => horray     //$passw
[cpassword] => horray  
[email] => b@b.b         //$email
[phone1] => 123456789    //$phone1
[phone2] => 987654321    //$phone2
[botchk] =>   
[tos] => on )
```

//$date = date("y/m/d");

i made sure that the data matches the rows data types... i tried changing and rewriting the code many times... nothing works! it is just stuck there!

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**\

**EDIT**
server was frozen (or something..), after reboot it accepted inputs.. sorry for the bother.. but after 6hrs of work you it is hard to think straight... error never changed even though sql kept changing, that was a clear mark.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Until you fix this, none of this code is going to work consistently.

Comment: Which, interestingly, would _also_ solve the problem he's currently experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

Two things; one is bad, and the other is very bad.

1. You're forgetting to put quotes around your string values, so the SQL expression is not a well written one.
2. You're running head first into an SQL Injection attack risk. [Please read this](http://bobby-tables.com) to see what it is and how to prevent it.

Comment: #1 is irrelevant if #2 is adhered to.

Comment: i am aware of both... it was failing to insert so tried minimizing the code.. i tried with the quote 3 times yet it never worked... but now "for some reason" it worked.. i just rebooted my PC and it started responding fine.. those were 3 hours i spent trying to solve this -.-  thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't just concatenate your variables into the SQL query string and expect it to work.  You need to add quotes around string values, and make sure every is properly formatted/escaped.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO net_users VALUES (NULL,'$fname','$mname','$lname','$dob','$uname','$pasw','$phone1','$phone2','$email',NULL,NULL,NULL,'$date');";
```

Though, I would *not* suggest doing it this way.  If you concatenate user input into an SQL query, you have just opened the door for SQL injection.  What you want to do is use "prepared statements".  What you do is add `?` to your query where you want the variable to go.  Then the variables are passed to a separate function.  No quoting, no escaping, no SQL injection worries.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','wisdom') or die("CONNECTION ERROR");
$query = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO net_users VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,NULL,NULL,NULL,?)');

// No quoting or escaping needed, this passes the values separate from the query
$query->bind_param('ssssssssss', $fname, $mname, $lname, $dob, $uname, $pasw, $phone1, $phone2, $email, $date);

// This actually runs the query
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Absolutely the right way to permanently fix this problem.

Comment: i knew about the real_escape_string but this is a weird one.. i saw it someplace else but now it caught my eyes! can you give me the name (or link) of this method so i can read it more about it please?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `real_escape_string` any more.  What I am using is called "prepared statements".  Check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php  Also see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Thanks a lot :) appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose the values by single quotes. Try adding single quotes to your values.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO net_users VALUES (NULL,'$fname','$mname','$lname','$dob','$uname','$pasw','$phone1','$phone2','$email',NULL,NULL,NULL,'$date');";
```

You also have an `sql` [`injection attack`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) risk. Suggest you to use [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) instead.

Comment: i tried that... did not work! it is screwing with me!!! i know that it does not accept it unless it is surrounded by  (').. but if you look at the error it is not showing the begning of the error... why???

Comment: actually it just worked.... this is making me mad.. i tried adding them 3 times now.. every-time it gave me an error. i think ill go take a shower, thanks.

Comment: This is not a solution by any stretch, this is just digging a deeper hole.